# Linear Algebra Matrix/Linear systems question (true or false)

Tags: linear-algebra

True or False?

Let $A$ be an $m x n$ matrix. If $m \lt n$, then for each **$b$** in $\mathbb R^{m}$ the linear system $Ax=b$ is either inconsistent or has infinitely many solutions.

Can anyone explain this only using beginner level linear algebra material (e.g. vector spaces, bases, linear independence/dependence) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is how it works for you. Because of $m <n$ the kernel of $A$ can not be trivial.
Because it's not trivial there is $v\in \text{kern}(A)$ with $v\neq 0$. Now let $x$ be a solution of $$A x=b.$$ We can construct infinitely many others solutions from this one, taking $$ A(x+\gamma v)=Ax + A (\gamma v)=Ax+ \gamma A v =Ax=b$$ for any $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: by kernel, do you mean null space?

Comment: yeah sry english is a foreign language :(

Comment: no worries. thanks for your help!